# Ошибка Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет.

Выполняю запрос

```
$scID= $this->ajax_model->getSubCatID($alias_subcategory);
```

Потом проверяю

```
if (!empty($scID)){
что то делаю}
```

Но выдает ошибку Trying to get property of non-object

Т.е. если данные есть то все ок, а если пустая то выдает ошибку? как можно от нее избавиться?

Comment: Покажи на какую именно строку ругается? Попробуй вывести полученное значение куда-нибудь, проверь его тип

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что в сообщении об ошибке указывается номер строки кода, где она возникает. приведите эту строку, а также окружающий ее код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($this->ajax_model) {
    $scID= $this->ajax_model->getSubCatID($alias_subcategory);
}
```